# Access an ip address on the host network inside kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

### How can I access a service on an IP address in my host's network?

Basically, I have 5 or 6 VMS on the same network and 3 of these VMS are used to create a Kubernetes cluster. One of these VMs hosts a private npm registry external to Kubernetes (192.168.2.x). I am using a gitlab runner that runs in the Kubernetes cluster. While doing an npm install during a build phase of a ci pipeline I get a time-out as the pod running as the gitlab build runner cannot access the private npm registry which is on host network via 192.168.2.x and not inside the Kubernetes cluster.

Is there a way to be able to access a service inside the same host network but not inside the Kubernetes cluster?

**Here is an example of the error msg inside the runner:**

> $ npm install
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN network SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: request to  https://devops.internal.ideam.co.za/repository/npm-group/fsevents failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.2.6:443
>
> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
>   npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
>   npm ERR! network request to > https://devops.internal.ideam.co.za/repository/npm-group/source-map failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.2.6:443
>   npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

As you can see once the FQDN that is protected via a trusted cert is resolved to the internal IP address this the host IP address of the npm registry is not accessible from inside the pod. I have made sure the external FQDN does resolve using busybox and nslookup command in the Kubernetes cluster in a debug pod.

### I have provided an explanatory diagram to illustrate:

[image]

Is this a network configuration issue? Does anybody know if this is possible or how to get this to work?

Comment: A couple things: This question is a little light on the development / code side which might make it a better candidate for Server Fault or Super User rather than Stack Overflow. But also, it probably makes sense here to describe the network setup, how Kubernetes was installed, and where it runs (on-prem? provider?). This should certainly be possible (I have Kubernetes run services that talk to other VMs outside of Kubernetes).

Comment: Thanks, Andy, The setup is on-prem, I used juju charms to do the install as minimalistic as possible for POC and Development. I am not much of an expert at Kubernetes and setup mostly defaults. I used **Calico** as the container network solution.

Comment: One interesting thing that jumps out at me is that the Juju charm for Calico default subnet at https://github.com/charmed-kubernetes/layer-calico/blob/master/config.yaml#L25 appears to overlap with your local network. Is it possible the Pods cannot route outside the cluster because the subnet mask doesn't allow so? You might try recreating it by setting another default Calico network that doesn't get near your regular network (maybe something like 172.168.0.0/16).

Comment: This is actually really useful and would make sense. This gives me something to look at. I will try this and see if it solves my issues

Comment: Hi! If you find a solution would you mind sharing it with the community? Thanks!